# SQL return max in unnest

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
table_a.col1,
table_a.col2,
array.col1
FROM
table_a
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(table_a.array) AS array
```

What should I do if I only want the query to return one `array.col1` per row in `table_a` (let's say I want only the `max` value for each case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select max(el)
        from unnest(a.array) el
       ) as max_el
from table_a a;
```